# Saving remaining lines to file

Tags: python, line

I have a file I read and if the line in file contains "something" it will save the file to another file and if then I am trying to save lines that doesn't contain it to a different file but it doesn't work.
Any help is appreciated. I am still a beginner in Python, so sorry if I am missing something silly.

```
with open("my.txt", errors='ignore') as f:
    lines = [l for l in f if "findme" in l]
    nolines = [l for l in f if "findme" not in l]
    with open("save.txt", 'a') as fi:
       for listitem in lines:
         fi.write(listitem)
    with open("remaining.txt", 'a') as fu:
       for listfail in nolines:
         fu.write(listfail)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that after the first looping through the lines of the file, your file pointer points at the end of the file. One way to solve your issue is to set the pointer back to the beginning with `file.seek(0)`, e.g.:

```
with open("my.txt", errors='ignore') as f:
    lines = [l for l in f if "findme" in l]
    f.seek(0)  # reset the file pointer position to the beginning
    nolines = [l for l in f if "findme" not in l]
    with open("save.txt", 'a') as fi:
       for listitem in lines:
         fi.write(listitem)
    with open("remaining.txt", 'a') as fu:
       for listfail in nolines:
         fu.write(listfail)
```

---

However, a better approach to the problem is to loop through the lines only once and write the lines on the go:

```
with open('my.txt', 'r', errors='ignore') as src_file, \
        open('save.txt', 'a') as tgt1_file, \
        open('remaining.txt', 'a') as tgt2_file:
    for line in src_file:
        print(line, file=tgt1_file if 'findme' in line else tgt2_file, end='')
```

this is shorter, clearer and more efficient both computation-wise (presumably faster, but have not tested) and memory-wise (as there is no need to create potentially large intermediate lists).

Note that the use of `print()` here, makes this code actually run somewhat slower than the original approach. This can be easily fixed by reverting to `file.write()`:

```
with open('my.txt', 'r', errors='ignore') as src_file, \
        open('save.txt', 'a') as tgt1_file, \
        open('remaining.txt', 'a') as tgt2_file:
    for line in src_file:
        (tgt1_file if 'findme' in line else tgt2_file).write(line)
```

Comment: I am getting errors, invalid syntax on with open line.
as src_file, <- error

Comment: @informedmoon sorry, forgot to add continuation line `\`, now should work

Comment: Your solution is slower and also makes empty lines, Hanefi's solution works better, but I still value your help and information a lot! :)

Comment: So, the empty lines was just a small bug related to how `print()` works. Simply adding `end=''` as a parameter to `print()`, would do the trick. Both issues are solved by avoiding the expensive (but perhaps more expressive for you as a beginner) `print()` call. Now the proposed solution has similar speed but it is more memory efficient.

Comment: from the looks of it speed seems almost identical yes and more memory efficient sounds good!
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @informedmoon if you feel any of the answers fulfills what you wanted to get with your question, you should consider accepting one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you read the contents of the file only once.

I suggest you read the contents first, and then split the list into two

```py
with open("my.txt", errors='ignore') as f:
    all_lines = [l for l in f]
    lines = [l for l in all_lines if "findme" in l]
    nolines = [l for l in all_lines if "findme" not in l]
    with open("save.txt", 'a') as fi:
       for listitem in lines:
         fi.write(listitem)
    with open("remaining.txt", 'a') as fu:
       for listfail in nolines:
         fu.write(listfail)
```

There are a number of improvements that can be made though.